# Action with different fulfilment URL based on user's location

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I work for a company that is building a Google Action which will be available in AU, NZ & UK. Depending on the location of the user, the fulfilment URL needs to be different as each country has its own APIs, etc.

We could achieve this easily by deploying three separate apps, restricted to their particular country, each having their own fulfilment URL. However, if my understanding is correct, they would all have different invocation names which is not ideal.

Another way we could potentially achieve this is by making the user choose which market they want (AU, NZ, UK) on the account linking page and then use the APIs for that market. However it doesn't seem to be a great UX.

Ultimately the key goals we're trying to achieve are

1. Users in AU, NZ & UK can all invoke the Google Action by saying "Ok Google, Open App", rather than "Ok Google, Open App NZ", "Ok Google, Open App UK", etc.
2. Users don't have to choose market (AU, NZ, UK) they belong to - it happens automatically
3. We can use the correct API based on the market the user belongs to.

Comment: Perhaps instead of thinking about separate fulfillment URLs for each of your markets, you have ONE URL which receives the Action SDK request and from there we identify the user making the request.  Based on the user or their profile, we can then identify which of the markets to be serviced and then process accordingly ... such as proxying the request to one of three separate fulfillment implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have different fulfillment URLs for the same Action.

You also have a slight issue when getting their location - you need to [request it explicitly from them](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information). Once you have this, however, you can [store it](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_across_conversations) (with their permission) to use it again in future requests, so you only have to do it once.

You *will* need to check to make sure it is one of the locations you serve, and you may want to allow them to change it (what if someone from the UK is traveling to AU?).